# What am I doing wrong that is causing this error with a custom viewpager in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

After looking at various tuts and SO questions, I'm pretty sure I know how to display limited results within a viewpager from a remote database. Yet when I run the app, I get the following error. I've checked the url through a browser with no errors so I know it can't be null so I'm confused and not sure where this is going wrong. The PHP code limits the results to the last 5 rows in the database in desc order.

**LogCat**

> Process: com.curtrostudios.custompagertest, PID: 22057
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.curtrostudios.custompagertest.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:59)
>       at com.curtrostudios.custompagertest.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:50)
>       at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
>       at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Main Activity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager pageView;
    private String TAG = "Featured View";
    private String FEAT_URL = "http://localhost/testing/featured.php";
    private ArrayList<FeaturedModel> fdata;
    private FeaturedAdapter featAdapt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        pageView = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.featuredView);

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(FEAT_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString()); try {
                            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                                String pid=response.getJSONObject(i).getString("pid");
                                String name=response.getJSONObject(i).getString("prod_name");
                                String img = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("prod_pic");

                                fdata.add(new FeaturedModel(pid, name, img));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        featAdapt=new FeaturedAdapter(MainActivity.this, fdata);
                        pageView.setAdapter(featAdapt);
                        //dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                //dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, TAG);





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Data Model**

```
    public class FeaturedModel {
    private String pid;
    private String prod_name;
    private String prod_pic;

    public FeaturedModel(String pid,String prod_name,String prod_pic){
        this.pid=pid;
        this.prod_name=prod_name;
        this.prod_pic=prod_pic;

    }

    public String getPID(){
        return pid;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return prod_name;

    }
    public String getImageURL(){
        return prod_pic;
    }


}
```

**Pager Adapter**

```
    public class FeaturedAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<FeaturedModel> feature;
    private Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public FeaturedAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<FeaturedModel> data) {

        feature=data;
        context=mainActivity;

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feature.size();
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView ftitle;
        NetworkImageView fimg;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feature_row, null);
        holder.ftitle=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.featTitle);
        holder.fimg=(NetworkImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.featImg);
        holder.ftitle.setText(feature.get(position).getName());

        // If you are using NetworkImageView
        holder.fimg.setImageUrl(feature.get(position).getImageURL(), VolleyController.getInstance().getImageLoader());


        container.addView(rowView);
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
    }

}
```

**Result from browser**

```
    [
    {
        "pid": "45",
        "prod_name": "Product 45",
        "prod_pic": "http://localhost/images/testone.png",
        "prod_desc": "some description",

    },
    {
        "pid": "44",
        "prod_name": "Product 44",
        "prod_pic": "http://localhost/images/testtwo.png",
        "prod_desc": "some description",

    },
    {
        "pid": "43",
        "prod_name": "Product 43",
        "prod_pic": "http://localhost/images/testone.png",
        "prod_desc": "some description",

    },
    {
        "pid": "42",
        "prod_name": "Product 42",
        "prod_pic": "http://localhost/images/testtwo.png",
        "prod_desc": "some description",

    },
    {
        "pid": "41",
        "prod_name": "Product 41",
        "prod_pic": "http://localhost/images/testone.png",
        "prod_desc": "some description",

    }
]
```

Comment: something is null in `onResponse` maybe `response` is `null` do you have `INTERNET` permission in your manifest?

Comment: Initialize your ArrayList<FeaturedModel> fdata.

Comment: @Blundell yes, I have internet permission in my manifest.

Comment: The exception tells you it's on line 59. Carefully look at that line. Has the arraylist been initialized before you add anything to it?

Comment: @AdeelShahzad can't believe I missed that but I initialized the arraylist and it works now. Thank you for pointing that out. Thank you to cricket_007 too!

Comment: @AdeelShahzad If you can, could you post an answer so I can accept it so you get credit? Also so anyone else that my have a similar issue that see's this in the future will know what to look for as well.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted my question but whoever did, it would be polite to explain why in the comments. If there was something wrong with my question, suggesting an edit or pointing out the problem would have been the more appropriate choice. This helps ensure questions are asked and formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ArrayList fdata is not initialized. Call `fdata = new ArrayList<>();` before adding/selecting items from it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have internet permission
   2.Make a `RequestQueue` Object

   RequestQueue queue =  olleyController.getInstance().getQueue();
2. add the `jsonObjectRequest` to queue

   queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
3. you can set `PagerAdapter` outside the `volley Anonymous class`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Adeel Shahzad pointed out my mistake. I forgot to initialize the arraylist.